# DataTable Select: double value could not filtered

Tags: c#, string, datatable

I am trying to select a datatable object. The code throw exception when my expression value is 82.5 (double).

```
_dataSet.Tables[2].Select("ProfitShareRatio = " + Convert.ToDouble(_listrow[m]["ProfitShareRatio"]));
```

P.s : `ProfitShareRatio` value is double in `_dataSet.Tables[2]`

ERROR:

> Syntax error in the expression.
>
> at System.Data.ExpressionParser.Parse()
>      at System.Data.DataExpression..ctor(DataTable table, String expression, Type type)
>      at System.Data.Select..ctor(DataTable table, String filterExpression, String sort, DataViewRowState recordStates)
>      at System.Data.DataTable.Select(String filterExpression)

EDIT 2: 
Same error occured when I use Decimal.

```
 _dataSet.Tables[2].Select("ProfitShareRatio = " + Convert.ToDecimal(_listrow[m]["ProfitShareRatio"]));
```

P.s 2:The problem is  `Convert.ToDecimal(_listrow[m]["ProfitShareRatio"])` is return value with comma like 82,50
I need to return value with dot like 82.50

Comment: Out of interest, does _dataSet.Tables[2].Select("ProfitShareRatio = 82.5") work? Are you sure the data type of ProfitShareRation in _dataSet.Tables[2] is double? So what does _dataSet.Tables[2].Columns["ProfitShareRation"].DataType give you?

Comment: @maycil can you explain us _listrow[m]["ProfitShareRatio"] ?

Comment: @dash _dataSet.Tables[2].Select("ProfitShareRatio = 82.5") is working.
_dataSet.Tables[2]["ProfitShareRatio"] is decimal.

Comment: @HichemC  _listrow[m]["ProfitShareRatio"] is a rate value that can be 1,0 to 100,00.

Comment: @maycil - if it's a Decimal, then why not use Convert.ToDecimal?

Comment: @HichemC I edit my answer but its same and not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
String.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"),"ProfitShareRatio =  {0}",Convert.ToDecimal(_listrow[m]["ProfitShareRatio"]))
```

Thanks to everybody. Problem is solved with changing culture to en-US. String format result is "ProfitShareRatio = 82.5"

Comment: my former answer was pretty close although we couldn't know that you were having a culture issue.

Comment: Yes dude, you are right. I noticed the problem at diffirent culture machine.